# Laravel SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I am trying to make a relationship with lecturers table and users table. So this is the code of create_lecturers_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('lecturers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');


            $table->integer('class03');
            $table->integer('class03_stream');
            $table->date('class03_from');
            $table->date('class03_to');

            $table->string('remarks')->nullable();

            $table->integer('created_user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('updated_user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('created_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('updated_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is the Lecturer model

```
class Lecturer extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'lecturers';

    protected $fillable = [

        'class03', 'class03_stream' ,'class03_from','class03_to','remarks','created_user_id','updated_user_id',

    ];

    public function user(){
      return $this->hasMany('PMS\User');
    }
}
```

This is the lecturer index function of the controller

```
public function index(Lecturer $model)
    {
        return view('lecturers.index',['lecturers' => $model->paginate(15)]);
    }
```

This is the create_users_table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('user');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('usertype');
            $table->boolean('activestatus')->default(false);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }
```

This is the User model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;



    public function lecturer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('PMS\Lecturer');
    }


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','usertype',
    ];
```

With this what I wants to do is to view the User's name who will create the lecturer via System.So that I have echo the user's name as below in the view.blade.php

`<td>{{ $lecturer->user->name }}`

When I go to the view it generate this error.

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.lecturer_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`lecturer_id` = 1 and `users`.`lecturer_id` is not null) (View: E:\BIT FINAL YEAR PROJECTS\20190419-using-template\resources\views\lecturers\index.blade.php)
```

Could someone please tell me what is the wrong .
Thanks

Comment: Your `users` table doesn't have a column called `lecturer_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have your Eloquent relationships the wrong way around. Try changing them to as follows:

**Lecturer**

```php
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('PMS\User', 'created_user_id');
}
```

**User**

```php
public function lecturers(){
    return $this->hasMany('PMS\Lecturer', 'created_user_id');
}
```